# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL db on Ubuntu 18.04 Server

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Having a time trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database on Ubuntu 18.04 server.

Here is my:
postgresql.conf file:

```
port=5432
listen_addresses='*'
```

pg_hba.conf:

```
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

firewall is currently disabled

here is the output when I did the command  (saw in another thread to do this...): 
`sudo netstat -ltpn`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      608/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      842/sshd            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2922/postgres       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1055/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      867/nginx: master p 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      842/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1055/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

I have restarted postgresql each when making a change using the command: 
`sudo service postgresql restart`.

I have tried to access the db using the python library psycopg2 on macOS and getting this error

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "<ip_address>" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

From the `netstat` output it is obvious that you didn't restart PostgreSQL after changing `listen_addresses`.